# Lotto Number Generator probabilities

Tags: probability

Imagine a lottery that you pick 3 numbered balls from a set of {1,2,3,4,5}

if i pick 3 numbers at once or peak them in sequence is there a difference in probabilities for each number picked ?

**Method A**

```
1. {1,2,3,4,5} shuffle and then picked at random 3
2. {1,2,4,5}   shuffle and then picked at random 5
3. {1,2,4}     shuffle and then picked at random 4
remainder set {1,2} picked resultSet{3,5,4}
```

**Method B**

```
1. {1,2,3,4,5} shuffle and then picked at random 2,5,4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the way in which you choose the balls doesn't affect the probability.

One has to make a particular assumption for it not to, though. That is: We don't know the configuration of the system and assume that a ball's position (and how its position affects the likelihood of it being picked) is unknown to us *before* selecting it. If a 5 is next to a 2, then its probability of being chosen must be the same. (This is a more intuitive way of saying that the probability of selecting a particular ball is independent of the probability of selecting another ball. The below explanation wouldn't work if even-numbered balls were magnetic, for example.)

We'll use your example as... an example:

The probability of picking any number is $\frac{1}{5}$, the probability of picking some second number is $\frac{1}{4}$, and the probability of picking a third number is $\frac{1}{3}$. So, now you have three numbers. The probability of picking these three particular numbers in this sequence is $$\frac{1}{5} \times \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{60}$$ Note: The above probability preserves order. That is, the probability that you choose those three balls *in that particular order* is $\frac{1}{60}$. If you want to disregard order we can do this: Every three numbers has $3! = 6$ different rearrangements. So, the probability of getting three numbers in *any* order is $\frac{1}{60} \times 6 = \frac{1}{10}$.

Now, say you pick three balls at the same time. Instead of looking at individual balls, we look at all possible combinations of *three* balls. In other words, we look at the number $${5 \choose 3} = \frac{5!}{3!(5-3)!} = \frac{1}{10}$$ And voila! We get the same probability. Since choose-numbers don't preserve order, we can do a similar thing: We know that each set of three balls has six different orderings. Thus, if the probability of getting three balls in *any* order is $\frac{1}{10}$, the probability of getting a particular order must be $\frac{1}{10} \div 6 = \frac{1}{60}$

Comment: but one shuffle of the complete set is different than 5 shuffles from a decreasing in size set, mathematically might be the same but "practically" i think its different. each shuffle brings a different "kind" of probability (different conditions)

Comment: Practically, they're also the same. If you were to perform this experiment many times, you'd get the same types of ratios. Try it. :)

Comment: Limitation of what probability theory describes. If you have a system A and System B and both produce the same output probability if you apply an operation F it doesnt mean that both systems are equivalent or equal that is what i'm saying...

Comment: @firephil I'm sorry. I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: Imagine you have two coins A,B that are built from different material i.e gold and silver and you apply an (operation F=flip the coin) they may appear to produce the same probabilities p1,p2 = 1/2 but because they are in essence different systems p1!=p2. I cant explain it better

Comment: I think the problem here would be solved if you answer this question: Can you define "different system"? I understand now what you're trying to say—but I think the distinction you're making is a blurry one. For example, what if I consider *no* system to ever be the same, ever, because of differences in atomic structure, quantum motion, etc.? What constitutes a "system" is its context. For example, consider looking at a coin as a simple probabilistic system: Then a wood coin, a gold coin, and a steel coin are all the same system, with the same *flip* operation.

Comment: On the other hand, consider looking at a coin as an electrical system: Then the wood, gold, and steel coin are **completely** different systems. The question you asked regards a probabilistic system; to bring about other system-quantifiers, irrelevant to the actual question, will just confuse things. :)

Comment: Probability theory is useful but in essence its an illusion that is, my main point. Our inability with the current tools to differentiate between different systems (sets of variables i.e material, weight, size of the coins etc) that have the same average probability. 
The three "systems" (coin1, coin2, coin3) might converge differently to the average probability of 1/2 hence my statement different “probabilities”
The same applies to my question, 5 shuffles of a decreasing set of balls vs 1 shuffle of a constant set of balls

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYnJv68T3MM